# How do I get all the values of one specific column in list form on a website table?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to make a list of all the values in an entire column, on a table on a website.

Right now, I am trying a different method which is clicking on the specific html code and performing the action through and through. But it would be much faster to do so if I can loop each value of a list through the process.

What I am doing right now: Invoice top is the top invoice in the table (I used Absolute XPATH for this reference)

I need to make a list of all the invoice numbers

```
def loop(Invoice_Top,driver):
    while Invoice_Top is not '' or Invoice_Top is not 0:
            Invoice_Top.click()
```

And after the .click(), the entire process is performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think using `Invoice_Top` is a good approach to doing this, because it represents a single row, but it sounds like you are trying to get the invoice number from ALL rows. You'd have better luck grabbing a list of all the `td` elements containing an invoice number, and looping through them from there.

```
# get all invoice cells -- skip the first tr element, because it just contains column headers
invoice_cells = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table/tbody/tr[not(contains(@class, 'printonly'))]/td[1]")

for invoice_cell in invoice_cells:
    print(invoice_cell.text)
```

This should print the invoice numbers -- the XPath is picking the first `td` element from every row, which is the invoice number in this case, and printing its contents to the console.

Comment: I think you'd want "//tr", for all rows? and skip the first row.

Comment: I tested my query against a generic HTML table, and it looks like just `/tr` is returning all of the rows. But thanks for pointing out the issue with skipping the first row -- I just edited my answer to handle that based on the `tr` classname.